# Auth0 - metadata for non-interactive clients

Tags: java, spring-security, auth0

I'm evaluating [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) as an authentication/authorization service for our new project.

I would like to expose some REST APIs without UI at this point.

So I believe clients won't need to log-in but just send an authorization header with a JWT token (I'll send this token by e-mail at this point).

I understood that in Auth0 there are "non-interactive" clients for this (Am I right?)
In my understanding, every potential customer will be a client and I'll create a dedicated client configuration in Auth0 for it.

So I've created a client like this following the tutorial found [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security)
(we've a java shop, so I've naturally opted for spring security) and it works.

Now I would like to put some metadata on such a client. I've tried to add the "Application Metadata".
I would like to access this metadata on server (from java Spring rest controller), but I see that its not in the JWT token

My question is what is the right implementation for this? How should I get this information on server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing the notions of "Clients" and "Users".  A Client in Auth0 is an access channel to the Auth0 back-end.  In some (unusual) approaches to multi-tenancy you might go with multiple Auth0 clients, but I doubt it.

What I think you want is: One (1) Client and many Users.

The app_metadata are then associated with the User records.